# Side Effects with Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am currently trying to instrument some code when running a test-suite in javascript, but am having issues when it comes to actually spitting out data when using mocha.

It seems like when I try to print something out (or even write to a file), I have no success.

See below for a sample:

## main.js

```
var Foo = require('./lib')

Foo()

module.exports = function(a) { return a + 1}
```

## lib.js

```
var fs = require('fs')
module.exports = function() {
  setTimeout(function() { 
    fs.writeFile('test_file', 'hello world', function(){})
    console.log('hello finished')
  }, 1000)
  console.log('hello begin')
}
```

## test.js

```
var x = require('./main')
describe("some test", function() {
  it("should do something", function(done) {
     done()
   })
})
```

The result should create a file named `test_file` with the contents of `hello world`.

I have created a repository that has the full example that can be cloned and tested easily.

https://github.com/hamhut1066/mocha-mockup

Answer (score 0):

In your test file, you're importing `main`. But `main` is only what you exported in `main.js` : `function(a) { return a + 1}`.

You should export the whole file :

```
var Foo = require('./lib')

module.exports = function(a) { 
  Foo();
  return a + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Duno how exactly Mocha works (i.e. how it manages thread pool for tests or even does it have that pool), but it looks like Mocha kills threads after test finishs.

So setTimeout will not fire event as thread is dead already.

(while setTimeout(..., 1) will fire event - just try it)

Comment: Cheers, this is what I was looking for. You don't know how to get mocha to stop killing threads do you?

Comment: No. And it sounds like 'how to broke mocha'. As for me, it looks like you have bad designed tests - I mean if you want to check something after some time of waiting then you should not done() you tests until that.

Comment: Essentially I'm trying to instrument a 3rd party library which uses mocha to run tests (the tests are sane). I want to gather data at runtime, then output it to stout after all tests have run. I am in no way concerned at the quality of the tests.

Comment: You can summarize results at some object and print them all it at after() / afterEach() hook - exactly what you are donig. But why you need that setTimeout, I still cannot understand.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is that just using `done` like you do does not work. Mocha gets to your test, executes it, `done` is called right away. So Mocha figures it is done and exits.

There's also the fact that `lib.js` is badly designed. You could implement it like this instead:

```
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = function(cb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        fs.writeFile('test_file', 'hello world', cb);
        console.log('hello finished');
    }, 1000);

    console.log('hello begin');
};
```

I've just added the `cb` parameter to the function exported and passed it to `fs.writeFile`.

A test that would minimally check for the correct file would do this:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const lib = require("./lib");
const assert = require("assert");
describe("some test", function() {
    it("should do something", function(done) {
        lib(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                done(err);
            }

            fs.readFile("./test_file", function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    done(err);
                }

                assert.equal(data, "hello world");
                done();
            });
        });
    });
    after(function (done) {
        fs.unlink("./test_file", function () {
            // We don't want a cascading failure here if the test
            // above failed to create the file so we ignore errors
            // here.
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Note how I'm testing `lib.js` directly above. That's how unit tests work. Test the minimal unit of functionality. Then you could write a test to check that `main.js` calls the function exported by `lib.js`.

Comment: While I agree that this is better designed, the example I provided was a minimal example (not necessarily a model example). Please see the answer from @Artem who points me in the right direction, but does not know the full details required to work around the issue.

Comment: That answer is incorrect. There's no "thread" involved in any of this.

Comment: if that answer is incorrect, then could you maybe explain why the event never fires?

Comment: Very first paragraph: "So Mocha figures it is done and exits." That's why the event never fires.